# My Hashmap object value list object return only last object i was put in ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>>();

Tags: java, android

this is my code for detail description.
i get size of Hashmapis ok. but when i try to get `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>` using key, all the ArryList have size 1.

```
private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> settingInObject;
private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> parentItemList;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>> childItemList;

settingInObject = new ArrayList<>();
parentItemList = new ArrayList<>();
childItemList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>>();


   ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (Map<String, Object> objectMap : settingInObject) {
        if (objectMap.get("IsCheked").toString().equals("1")) {
            if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
                childItemList.put(parentItemList.get(parentItemList.size()).get("TitleDesc").toString().trim(), arrayList);
                arrayList.clear();
            }
            parentItemList.add(objectMap);
        } else {
            arrayList.add(objectMap);
        }
    }
```

is there i do something wrong??

Comment: you efinitely are doing something strange and weird, if you have such a complex structure

Comment: gotta agree with Vlad, it looks too complex, you may need to revise what you want to do.

Comment: Yehh, this is complected,but i want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling

```
arrayList.clear();
```

while under arayList you have still reference to added object - in result you are clearing the list that is already put in the map

If you want to have new empty list in `arrayList` you need to reinstance it rather

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

Comment: but when i print size  of  arryList, it always right.

Comment: if every time i can assign new ArryList object, i can lost my previous added Map<String,Object>> in "arrayList".